# BottomSheetDialog not showing?

Tags: android, material-design, bottom-sheet

I'm trying to implement the new BottomSheetDialog, but when I call `.show()` it display the background shadows but not my layout.

This is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:paddingStart="8dp"
            android:paddingEnd="8dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Notes"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

            <Switch
                android:id="@+id/notes"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

And then:

```
    mSettingsDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(this);
    View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.reader_settings,  null);
    mSettingsDialog.setContentView(v);
    mSettingsDialog.show();
```

How can I  fix this issue?

Comment: Where you able to fix this?

Comment: Do not use constraintLayout as a root layout when showing BottomSheetDialog on it...

Comment: Few steps we can check:

1. Use static method newInstance
2. Try linearLayoutCompat as a root layout
3. Try a colourful background to get an idea
4. Try match_parent height for the root layout
5. Make sure that dismiss or cancel is not being called
6. Check visibility
7. Restart both: PC and Device

Answer (score 2):

I got this problem, the reason for me is

1. the dialog XML name is same with other module XML file name, so try rename it to another one
2. check the layout file, maybe it has some error, keep the simplest layout test it.

Answer (score 0):

Few steps we can check:

1. Create and use the static method `newInstance` and call the `show()` method on it.
2. Try `LinearLayoutCompat` as a root layout.
3. Try a colourful background to the root layout to get an idea.
4. Try `match_parent` height for the root layout.
5. Make sure that the `dismiss()` or `cancel()` is not being called on it immediately.
6. Check visibility.
7. If it contains a `recyclerView`, make sure that it has items, `getItemCount` is not returning 0, and that we are setting up the values properly!
8. Restart both: PC and Device.